# Manifest Permissions vs App Setttings Permissions

Tags: android, permissions

Do manifest permissions like "SEND_SMS" override the app permissions in Settings like "SMS" if it is set to off? The don't seem to set the later to on.

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
```

SMS for the app settings set to "on" is expected. No error messages are being displayed.

Comment: Nope. Those `<uses-permissions>` elements simply declare which permissions your app might use, at some point. The switches on the Settings page override everything, so the user has final say as you what your app is allowed to do. If you're having problems with an SMS function, you'll need to provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check all the permissions at runtime...in your MainActivity, so that if permissions are being off from settings then it will again ask for permissions when you open the application.

Call this method in onCreate() of your MainActivity.

```
private boolean checkAndRequestPermissions() {

    int SEND_SMS = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS);
    int RECEIVE_SMS = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS);
    int READ_SMS = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_SMS);

    List<String> listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();

    if (SEND_SMS != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS);
    }
    if (RECEIVE_SMS != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS);
    }
    if (READ_SMS != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.READ_SMS);
    }

    if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, listPermissionsNeeded.toArray
                (new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]), 101);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Your response create a path for me to explore which has resulted in the code I needed.